# Arabic characters in URL using URLRAW

Tags: bibliographies, citing, urls, arabic, biblatex-chicago

I am citing a website which has arabic characters in its URL. To avoid having to many %%% in my citations, I came across adding the field urlraw to the bib items. But what I get in the footnotes and the bibliography is this:
[image: footnote] [image: bibliography]

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright,12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%%%Bookmarks%%%%
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=false,linkcolor=false,urlcolor=false,bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{scrextend}
%%%%language settings%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}

%%%%Fonts%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont={Linux Libertine O C}]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.0,Mapping=arabicdigits,BoldFont=Amiri Bold]{Amiri}

%%%%biblatex%%%%%%
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeAutoQuote{»}{«}
\usepackage[backend=biber,notes, isbn=false,doi=false]{biblatex-chicago}
%%mention short title in subsequent citations%
\renewbibmacro*{cite:short:ibid}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:short}{\thefield{entrytype}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@online{ArsifMagalatAlmustaqbal,
  title = {Aršif maǧalat al-mustaqbal al-ʿarabī},
  url = {https://caus.org.lb/product-category/مجلة-المستقبل-العربي/},
  urlraw = {https://caus.org.lb/product-category/مجلة-المستقبل-العربي/},
  urldate = {2022-10-12},
  langid = {arabic},
  organization = {{Center for Arab Unity Studies}},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%URLRAW%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{%
  \mkbibacro{URL}\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{#1}{\nolinkurl{\thefield{urlraw}}}}
    {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
     \expandafter
     \nolinkurl
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
     \expandafter
       {\thefield{urlraw}}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\blindtext \autocite{ArsifMagalatAlmustaqbal}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

What can I do to have the arabic charcters appear right in the footnote and the bibliography?

Comment: that is not a MWE, it is too long and it can't be compiled.

Comment: Yes, I edited it now and made it shorter

Comment: copy your code in a new document and test it.

Comment: It should work now, the first line was omitted, sorry about that.

Comment: do you use lualatex or xelatex?

Comment: I use xelatex ..

Comment: more difficult. Basically the url package can't handle arabic. So you shouldn't use \nolinkurl, but simply typeset the field with a font that can handle both english and arabic, so something like `\href{#1}{{\arabicfont\thefield{urlraw}}}`  (but I have no idea how the right-to-left should be handled in such a url).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139944/discussion-between-muhammed-ragab-and-ulrike-fischer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution suggested by [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) worked for me. I just had to add the command `\sloppy`before the `\printbibliography` so that the urls won't go off page limit. This MWE should explain it

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright,12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%%%Bookmarks%%%%
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=false,linkcolor=false,urlcolor=false,bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{scrextend}
%%%%language settings%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}

%%%%Fonts%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont={Linux Libertine O C}]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.0,BoldFont=Amiri Bold]{Amiri}

%%%%biblatex%%%%%%
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeAutoQuote{»}{«}
\usepackage[backend=biber,notes, isbn=false,doi=false]{biblatex-chicago}
%%mention short title in subsequent citations%
\renewbibmacro*{cite:short:ibid}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:short}{\thefield{entrytype}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@online{ArsifMagalatAlmustaqbal,
  title = {Aršif maǧalat al-mustaqbal al-ʿarabī},
  url = {https://caus.org.lb/product-category/مجلة-المستقبل-العربي/},
  urlraw = {https://caus.org.lb/product-category/مجلة-المستقبل-العربي/},
  urldate = {2022-10-12},
  langid = {arabic},
  organization = {{Center for Arab Unity Studies}},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%URLRAW%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{%
  \mkbibacro{URL}\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{#1}{\arabicfont{\thefield{urlraw}}}}
    {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
     \expandafter
     \nolinkurl
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
     \expandafter
       {\thefield{urlraw}}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\clearpage
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\blindtext \autocite{ArsifMagalatAlmustaqbal}
\sloppy
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```